# Two lines in a single node in Forest

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree, forest

I have recently switched from the tikz_qtree package to forest. Now I'm trying to change my trees to fit the forest coding. However, I can't find the way to let a single node contain two lines. I do not want the I-node in my example to branch to are. In the tikz-qtree package this could be done with the command:

```
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}



 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{forest}
 \usepackage{ucs}
 \usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
 \geometry{a4paper} 
 \usepackage{gb4e}
 \usepackage{flexisym}

 \begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{forest}, baseline
[IP, 
[Spec]
[I\textprime,
    [I \\ are]
    [VP]
]]
 \end{forest}
 \end{exe}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To do this in `forest` you also need to tell it to align node text as `center`.  I've added a `qtree` style which does this for every node and also makes the branches join unlike the default `forest` style, which is IMO somewhat ugly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{qtree/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, 
           child anchor=north,align=center,inner sep=0pt}}}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}, baseline, qtree
[IP 
[Spec]
[I\textprime,
    [I\\are]
    [VP]
]]
 \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: What do you mean by 'must be bracketed'? You don't need the curly brackets around the multiline node, by the way.

Comment: Yes you're right. And the extra code in my tree was just a leftover.  So now my answer looks like yours.

Comment: I've changed my answer so it just makes the point about adding `baseline` to the style. I did delete it completely but then thought that bit might be useful. I'll delete if you prefer, though.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me.  I was too busy at the time of your original comment to respond otherwise I would have corrected this sooner.

Answer (score 6):

This is a small supplement to [Alan Munn's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238711/). If all of your trees styled with `qtree` should be aligned with `baseline`, you can add this to the `qtree` style also:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  qtree/.style={
    baseline,
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
      inner sep=1pt,
    }}}
\usepackage{flexisym}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  qtree,
  [IP
    [Spec]
    [I\textprime,
        [I\\are]
        [VP]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: simpler code]